# Kolla-ansible openstack: Docker version failure

Tags: python, docker, pip, ansible, openstack

I have encountered a problem during a deploy of openstack pike.

There's an error running pre-check command.

> Kolla-ansible version 6.0.0.0rc2, Ubuntu Server 16 LTS [error][1]

I've found out that the required docker version is `>=2.4.6`.

My current is `1.12.6`.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result | failed or result.stdout | regex_replace('.*(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).*', '\\1') | version_compare(docker_version_min, '<')' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'failed'. String: {% if result | failed or result.stdout | regex_replace('.*(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+).*', '\\1') | version_compare(docker_version_min, '<') %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}

So, I tried to upgrade it by running command

```
sudo pip install -U docker==2.4.2
```

But `docker version` still says it is `1.12.6` and an error occurs.

**My question is**: do I have to upgrade docker in other way, change something in kolla-ansible playbooks, or maybe something else?

PS I know pike, Ubuntu srv 16 and 6.0.0.0rc2 are a little bit outdated, but its just for my university project :)

Comment: Can we see the part of ansible code that contains `result | failed`? Does the filter exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`failed` is not a [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) but a [test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html).

Using tests with the filter syntax used to be allowed. It has been [deprecated in ansible 2.5 (with warnings) and totally removed in ansible 2.9](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing/sanity/no-tests-as-filters.html).

The correct syntax is:

```
result is failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you installed the wrong docker.

Kolla needs docker engine. You should install docker-ce by following this:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

And then try again.

Also remove docker from pypi:

```
pip uninstall  docker
```

And the one from apt:

```
sudo apt remove docker
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in ansible. Like @Zeitounator said, that script worked only in ansible 2.5 or less, so this one solved my problem:

```
sudo -H pip install ansible==2.5.6
```

But another fail is:

> TASK [prechecks : Checking docker SDK version] *******************************************************************************************
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python", "-c", "import docker; print docker.**version**"], "delta": "0:00:00.014776", "end": "2020-01-21 14:35:06.561138", "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-01-21 14:35:06.546362", "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"\", line 1, in \nImportError: No module named docker", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"\", line 1, in ", "ImportError: No module named docker"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

solution is:

```
sudo pip install docker
```